# CMIS select statement to Alfresco Share, prevent unwanted symbols

Tags: alfresco

I have filter.java class , here comes all date from my `.xhtml`,  filter has 2 states,  `detailed` which works fine, and `general`.

problem with general search is, it builds me SELECT statems like:

```
select cmis:objectId from dvsm:manual_doc WHERE IN_FOLDER('xxx') and  ( dvsm:reg_num like '%Test%'  or dvsm:receiver like '%Test%'  or dvsm:title like '%Test%'  )
```

So general does search  by 3 columns.

My problem is, when  I am using general search, and if user does search by some random symbols, like `" <> ,. ! ()....."` and so on, it returns full list.

**Edit** but if user does general search by some random letters, that does not exist in a table, it works fine,and returns nothing.

I tried some weird `replace` functions, but noone worked well for me, and it's not some regular databse, so some SQL functions might not work..

I am using Java8, Tomcat7,  JSF 2.2, Primefaces 5.1, Mojara 2.2

Comment: Please improve your question. As it stands now it is neither java nor jsf related. The title is 'wrong' to in that 'java select' is nothing. Java-se does not have selects like this

Comment: I hardly know how to improve my question, because, in my mind, ( I may be wrong) there should be simple solution.

I can geneate SELECT statement in any way I want, I just need to know, how my SELECT should look like, to skip those symbos